# Unsure which command to install Virtualwrapper with Python 3.7

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to install `virtualwrapper` and `Django`.
But I end up coming across these cmds:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 virtualenvwrapper
```

*or*

```
sudo apt install virtualenvwrapper
```

I'm not sure which `cmd` I need to use, to install `virtualwrapper`. I'm still need to install `Django`. Then `PyCharm IDE`. I don't want to end up ruining everything again

Comment: Python3 should be already installed in all the current flavors of Ubuntu. The first command installs `python3` (if not installed) and `virtualenvwrapper`. The second command just installs `virtualenvwrapper`. The comand `apt` is more recent and now recommended and the command `apt-get` is old, but still available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to make you django project in **python3.x** version then you can install it by this way.

```
sudo apt-get install python3 virtualenvwrapper
```

Otherwise you can also use this command to install **virtualenvwrapper**

```
sudo apt install virtualenvwrapper
```